# Two fragments stacked ontop of each other using transactional ADD - how to prevent edit text gaining focus on bottom fragment?

Tags: android

Try stacking two fragments with editTexts on top of each other using an Add Transaction.   after that when you press the keyboard imeOption key next button the bottom fragment's edit text can gain focus. this is a security concern. user can type things into the bottom fragments edit text (blindly).  I tried the following code:

```
android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
```

but it has not helped at least on api 27.

my edit text itself looks like this, nothing special:

```
                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/et"
                                    android:layout_width="195dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                    android:hint="@string/enter_name"
                                    android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
                                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                                    android:textColorHint="#959595"
                                    android:textSize="11sp" />
```

the issue is very similar to [android tap jacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179773/android-tap-jacking-how-to-prevent-it)

i tried even doing this:

android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_two" thinking it would bypass and go directly to the edittext i want. but instead the bottom edit text still gains focus.

Comment: Why are you adding the fragment instead of replacing it?

Comment: becauase i did not want to keep making a network call. my api call is inside onViewCreated() .where would you put it ?

Comment: So do not call API again if you have the data required to show your fragment.

Comment: yeah thats true, but dont you think this a security problem.   i'll have to change a few things to get it to work.  thanks for the suggestion

Comment: remember to addToBackStack so that your fragment in not destroyed only your view is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue solution was surprising. recyclerview was stealing focus.  [see this SO incident:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923948/recycleview-steals-focus-when-inside-a-nestedscrollview)

adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the recyclerview stopped the issue.